# HTML how to automate the creation of/programmatically create divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 4x3 div grid box like this:

```
        <div id="MainDiv" style="border:1px solid black; width:122px; height:160px;">
        <div id="Column1" style="float:left">
            <div id="sq1" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq2" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq3" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq4" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Column2" style="float:left">
            <div id="sq5" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq6" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq7" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq8" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Column3" style="float:left">
            <div id="sq9" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq10" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq11" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
            <div id="sq12" style="width:40px; height:40px;">
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I write just a few lines of code to automate the entire process?

Comment: so you want a row*col div box?

Comment: What do you want, a tool that generating the code so that you can copy or a function that generating the codes when the page loads?

Comment: javascript, so it is the latter one?

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnMJq/1/

is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script to iterate and dynamically create elements.

This code works.
    
    
    ||Working with elements||

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_div = null;
var mainDiv = null;
var column = null;
var sq = null;
function addElement()
{
  // create a new div element
  // and give it some content
  mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
  mainDiv.setAttribute('id', 'MainDiv');  
  mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'border:1px solid black; width:122px; height:160px;');

  var i=0,id;
  var k= 1;
  for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
      column = document.createElement("div");
      column.setAttribute('id', 'Column' + (j+1));  
      column.setAttribute('style', 'float:left');

      for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
          sq = document.createElement("div");
          sq.setAttribute('id', "sq" + k);  
          sq.setAttribute('style', 'width:40px; height:40px;');
          k++;

          column.appendChild(sq);
      }

      mainDiv.appendChild(column);
  }
  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(mainDiv, my_div);
}

</script>

<body onload="addElement()">
<div id='org_div1'> The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
</body>
</html>
```